# Can we change weight matrix in keras after each epoch?

Tags: keras, neural-network, perceptron

I want to know how can I change some weights in the weight matrix of a perceptron in keras. for example, I have a simple code of a multi-layer perceptron and I want to assign some weights to be zero before training or change some weights to zero during training. IS it possible? How?